# Azure arm template validation

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

My ARM template code fails with the following validation error.
[image]

The Domain join should wait until the custom script extension is complete. Kindly please see code below. I can't get my head around how the resource and subresource dependency work and how to name the resource. Appreciate if you can guide me to an article to learn.

```
   {
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/cse')]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
    "location": "[variables('varlocation')]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
      "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
      "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
      "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
      "settings": {
        "fileUris": [
          "https://XXXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/powershelscripts/sqlcluster/InstallAdditionalModules.ps1"
        ]
      },
      "protectedSettings": {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted ./sqlcluster/InstallAdditionalModules.ps1",
        "storageAccountName": "sdfsdfsdfsdf",
        "storageAccountKey": "sdsdfsdf/BH9C+fdgdfgdfgdfg+fgdfgdfg=="
      }
    },
    "copy": {
      "name": "WinFeatures",
      "count":"[variables('varvmCount')]"
    }
 },

 {
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/joindomain')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": ["[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/cse')]"            
               ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "Name": "[variables('vardomainToJoin')]",
      "User": "[concat(variables('vardomainToJoin'), '\\', variables('vardomainUsername'))]",
      "Restart": "true",
      "Options": "[variables('vardomainJoinOptions')]"
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "Password": "[variables('vardomainPassword')]"
    }
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "joindomain",
    "count":"[variables('varvmCount')]"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resourceId is wrong, should be this:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions',concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1)),'extensions')]"
```

or simply:

```
concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/extensions')
```

what the error tells you - you have 3 segments here: `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions`, but only 1 after that: `concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/extensions'))`.

But it should have 2 segments because its trying to do this:

```
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{segment1}/extensions/{segment2}
```

Working repro:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "varnodeNamePrefix": "testing"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/cse')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                        "https://XXXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/powershelscripts/sqlcluster/InstallAdditionalModules.ps1"
                    ]
                },
                "protectedSettings": {
                    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted ./sqlcluster/InstallAdditionalModules.ps1",
                    "storageAccountName": "sdfsdfsdfsdf",
                    "storageAccountKey": "sdsdfsdf/BH9C+fdgdfgdfgdfg+fgdfgdfg=="
                }
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "WinFeatures",
                "count": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/joindomain')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions',concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1)),'cse')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "Name": "yyy.zzz",
                    "User": "[concat('xxx', '\\', 'xxx')]",
                    "Restart": "true"
                },
                "protectedSettings": {
                    "Password": "xxx"
                }
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "joindomain",
                "count": 3
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

full working example: https://paste.ee/p/XlBHY (basically its the same as the one written above)

Comment: Thanks.. I this what I am confused of.. I named the custom extension as concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/joindomain'). My understanding (which is wrong as you know) is that the primary resource name is what we should use in the depended resource.. and what is a segment and where can I learn more about it.

Comment: well, a segment = anything between `/`, you resource name is fine, thats what it should be. the error is in the depends on parameter, like i specified

Comment: Sorry. I am still not following you. 
new-azResourceGroupDeployment : 10:27:37 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 
'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XX-XXX-UKW-XXX/extensions/extensions' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.

Comment: new-azResourceGroupDeployment : 10:51:49 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'DI-DEV-XXX-DB1/joindomain' at line '439' and column '9' is 
not valid: The resource identificator 'DI-XXX-UKW-DB1/extensions' is malformed. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.. Please see 
https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.

Comment: "dependsOn": ["[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/extensions')]"            
               ],

Comment: no idea what you are doing wrong here, can you supply a repro? also, I'd change the script extension resource name to something meaningful, not that it should matter, but its really misleading.

Comment: this doesnt work? I cant believe it, can you supply a repro? supplied mine that works fine

Comment: uploaded to Gdrive https://drive.google.com/open?id=12UCYLL42aTvkfLoNhU15w4Ag9Vn7MidQ

Comment: Interesting. in the custom script and the dc join section you changed the position of COPY and DEPENDSOn. Can you please tell me a bit more of it..

Comment: it doesnt really matter. its just my personal preference, i always do them in the same order (top to bottom), apiversion, name, type, location, copy, dependson, other top level things, properties. I've also deleted tags, just to simplify things, you can put them back in